# Denumerably many isomorphism types

Tags: first-order-logic

[Computability and Logic by Boolos and Burgess](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MA_Algebra/MAml_Mathematical%20logic/Boolos%20G.,%20Burgess%20J.P.,%20Jeffrey%20R.C.%20Computability%20and%20logic%20%284ed.,%20CUP,%202002%29%28ISBN%200521007585%29%28370s%29_MAml_.pdf) says that formula $\Gamma_d$ in example 12.12

```
∀x∀y(∃u(u ≠ x ∧ u ≡ x) ∧ ∃v(v ≠ y ∧ v ≡ y)) → x ≡ y)
```

supports models, whose domain is partitioned into equivalence classes of any size, e.g.

[image]

is possible. Yet, I do not understand how this is possible. Suppose my x is the first dot. Then, I can find u, which is the second dot. Similarly, let y be the first dot in the second equivalence class and another dot v is in its companion in the eqivalence class. The formula says that x and y must be in the same equivalence class. But they are obviously not!

Are they trying to cheat me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not trying to cheat you. You need to read the text of Example 12.12, following the formula.  It says:

> A denumerable model of $\Gamma_d$ will consist of a denumerable set $X$ with an equivalence relation in which any two elements $a$ and $b$ that are not isolated, that is, that are such that each is equivalent to something other than itself, are equivalent to each other.

Thus $x$ and $y$ in your example must be equivalent in the model, and the picture is not an accurate representation of what $\Gamma_d$ captures.

Comment: The the illustration is indeed inappropriate. My bad. Sorry for the blunder.